# CSS :hover to force element offset cross-browser solution needed

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, offset

I have a rather interesting problem, and wondered if it could be done purely in CSS. I know you can use webkit moz transforms, or javascript, but is there another simple CSS cross browser solution to this?

I have a box with a class container say

```
.container
{
 position: absolute;
 border: black 1px solid;
 top: 100px;
 left:100px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}
```

Now what I want to do is on mouseover (CSS hover) is enlarge the box to 30px by 30px around a central point somewhere in the approximate centre of the 10x10 box, returning to the original container when I mouse out. Something along the lines of:

```
.container:hover
{
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 top: 90px;
 left:90px;
}
```

Now the difficulty comes in that the `top` and `Left` positions are set into the HTML being sent from the database, and therefore do not appear in the CSS file.

The option is that I dynamically generate the CSS file from the DB data, and effectively create a class for every object (I really think this is a bad idea) or I use Javascript to manage some calculation `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` but this strikes me as being not very elegant. It's what I'm doing now. eeeugh.

So come on guys is there a better CSS solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it just the top/left then you can ignore those and use the margins to move them around (*provided that you know the dimensions*)

```
.container:hover
{
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left:-10px;
 margin-top:-10px;
}
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CuuNW/

---

The important calculation is that the margin need to match the half of the size increase that occurs on hover.

so, 30 pixel final size minus 10 pixel initial size is 20 pixels. You need to offset (*using margins*) 20/2 = 10 pixels.

Comment: Great way of doing it without any extra markup like I crammed into my post. This is the way to go.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. BTW that's why I chose those dimensions;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is my opinion that Javascript **is** the most elegant solution.

The purpose of client-side scripting is for client-side interaction, which is exactly what you're trying to do.

This isn't an answer, per se, to your question "*is there a better CSS solution*," but I think Javascript **is** the *better solution*.  A CSS solution would be hacky at best, and probably wouldn't work.

Comment: you are of course right about javascript being all about client side manips. I'm not sure I agree that CSS is "hacky at best" hence the webkit and moz efforts, and presumably the future of CSS

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `top` and `left` styles being sent with the `HTML` by using `!important` in your `stylesheet`.

```
.container:hover
{
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 top: 90px !important;
 left:90px !important;
}
```

Comment: The example I gave there was to show the effect of what I wanted to happen. In reality I don't want every element with class `container` to jump to position top:90 left:90 when the mouse goes over it!

Comment: Fair enough!  But you could give the `div` a specific `ID` or `class` (if there are a few of them) and then use `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping `.container` in a parent element positioned with the `left` and `top` values from your database?

Given that markup, you wouldn't need to know the `left` and `top` explicitly for your `:hover` effect on `.container`, so you could use fixed values as they will be determined based on the `left` and `top` of `.container`'s offset parent.

For example, given this markup:

```
<div class="container-parent">
    <div class="container">
        ...   
    </div>
</div>
```

you'd need to position `.container-parent` using your `top` and `left` database values. From there, your CSS would look like:

```
.container-parent{
    left:224px; /* from DB */
    position: absolute;
    top:128px; /* from DB */
}

.container
{
 position: absolute;
 border: black 1px solid;
 top: 100px;
 left:100px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

.container:hover
{
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 top: -15px; /* new width / 2 to center box */
 left:-15px; /* new height / 2 to keep things centered */
}
```

Here, `.container` appears like it usually would at the `left` and `top` coordinates from your database, but on `:hover` shifts itself -15px to the `left` and `top`. Since it is inside a positioned parent, those new `left` and `top` values will be equal to your original values - 15px.

Is that what you're looking to do?